# \line(1,0){5cm} gives error

Tags: errors

I am trying to create a signature line, like this:

```
\begin{flushright}
\line(1,0){5cm}

Dženan Zukić
\end{flushright}
```

However, latex gives me the following error messages for the second line:

```
pdflatex> ! Missing number, treated as zero.
pdflatex> ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
```

The PDF look just like I expect (a short horizontal line for my signature).
Do you have some suggestion about how to get rid of the compiler error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `\line` is as if from the `picture` environment. Then it should be `\line(1,0){length}`, where `length` is in internal `picture` units (points, if not changed). But probably more useful would be, say, `\rule{5cm}{0.2pt}`.

Answer (score 3):

The macros from the `picture` environment are using factors for the unit `\unitlength` instead of dimensions:

```
\begingroup
  \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}%
  \line(1,0){5}%
\endgroup
```

Package `picture` extends the syntax of these macros to allow the specification of dimensions:

```
\usepackage{picture}
...
\line(1,0){5cm}
```

Or a different way is the use of `\rule`, e.g.:

```
\rule{5cm}{.4pt}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what package you intend to use with that command, but you don't need any special package if you use a `\rule`.  The first `[]` argument is a vertical shift, the second argument is the horizontal length, and the last argument is the vertical thickness.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
body text

\raggedleft
\rule[.3ex]{5cm}{.1ex}\\
Your name goes here
\end{document}
```

Comment: `flushright` is the *environment*, `\raggedleft` the command form.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek  Thanks for reminding.  I always forget which way it goes.